# Error with Events lwc - [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to implement a small use case of CustomEvent() in lwc and it's not working. I have implemented custom events in past and I'm not sure what I missed here.

**Child Comp:**

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Child">
        <div class="child">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleClick}>Click Me!! </button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildCompDispatch extends LightningElement {
    sGreetingToParent = 'Hello, Welcome to Events!! ';
    handleClick(){
        const pressedEvent = new CustomEvent('press',{detail : this.sGreetingToParent});
        this.dispatchEvent(pressedEvent);
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title ="Parent">
        <div class="Parent" if:true={bShowGreeting}>
            <p ><b>{sGreeting}</b></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <c-child-comp-dispatch onpress={showgreeting}></c-child-comp-dispatch>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ParentCompHandle extends LightningElement {
    bShowGreeting = false;
    sGreeting = '';
    showGreeting(event){
        this.bShowGreeting = true;
        this.sGreeting = event.target.detail;
    }
}
```

It's a pretty simple and straight-forward component. Not sure what's missing here. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for your event there is no `event.target` so you are receiving this error. You should instead change to `event.detail` and use your detail. I would suggest restructuring the event that you are sending however to be:

```
this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'press', { detail: { value: this.sGreetingToParent }} )
```

and then access it in your method by getting `event.detail.value`  as you have now set this with a key for the attribute that you wish to receive. just assigning `event.detail` with the value will set detail to an object and the key would not exist for what you wish to receive.

also as mentioned in another response here, you should make sure that your javascript expressions match the case for their usage:

showGreeting is not the same as showgreeting. Javascript being case sensitive, you will want to have your `onpress={showGreeting}`

You may also consider some checks in place too in your method that shows the greeting, there are two ways to do it. One is new, one is old.

**Old:**

```
this.sGreeting = ( event && event.detail && event.detail.value ) || '';
```

**New: (not as widely supported in all browsers yet)**

```
this.sGreeting = event?.detail && event?.detail?.value
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. I'm not an expert with javascript and would like to understand how the old and new versions pointed in your answer actually work. Can you please point me to some documentation that I can use to understand this approach where we're using multiple '&&'

Comment: what you are doing is checking and getting a "truthy" value back from a `short circuit` evaluation: 

Truthy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
  
Short Circuit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Thank you.. I'll look into it!

Comment: sounds good. happy to help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is small typo in your parent component when you handle the event

Change the code to below , notice i have **showGreeting** instead of showgreeting

```
<c-child-comp-dispatch onpress={showGreeting}></c-child-comp-dispatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getRecordNotifyChange({recordId : this.currentRecordId});
```

this syntax will also give the above error,
below is correct one

```
getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId : this.currentRecordId}]);
```