# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I have a LWC that is used in different orgs. In one of them, when I dispatch an event like:

```
this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( 'press' ));
```

I am getting the `[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error` in that line (as per the Stack trace).

If I comment that line, then the error disappears.

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301125/error-with-events-lwc-noerrorobjectavailable-script-error) is the most similar question I have found but I am making no use of `event.target` so unfortunately it does not help.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace and code that handling the event?

Comment: Do you think it is due to the new Summer '21 release? Are you getting this error only on a sandbox where Summer '21 has been deployed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

As of my experience, the most common reason why `[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error` appears is when because a custom event is handled by a ghost method, meaning a method that does not exist on the JS controller.

For example, `oncustomevent={ghostMethod}`, where `ghostMethod` does not exist in the JS controller.

---

**Long version**

Let's say we have a child component like the following:

childComp.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Notify Parent Comp" onclick={notifyParent}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

childComp.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComp extends LightningElement {
    notifyParent() {
        const event = new CustomEvent('childnotification', { bubbles: true });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

which sends a `childnotification` event to `parentComp`

parentComp.html

```
<template>
    <div onchildnotification={ghostMethod}>
        <div onchildnotification={handleChildNotification}>
            <lightning-textarea value="Parent Component"></lightning-textarea>
            <c-child-comp></c-child-comp>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

parentComp.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ParentComp extends LightningElement {
    handleChildNotification() {
        console.log('Child Event arrived');
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, when the parent component receives `childnotification` event, apart from invoking `handleChildNotification` (which exists on
`parentComp.js` ) it's invoking `ghostMethod`, which does not exist on `parentComp.js`.

- Because of this reason, you will get this annoying `[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error` failure.

Points to take into account and why I consider this a Salesforce LWC Bug

- `parentComp.html` can be successfully deployed even if `ghostMethod` does not exist on `parentComp.js`
- As of my experience, you only get this error if `ghostMethod` has never existed in the LWC. If it has existed in a previous LWC version it will not fail (even if the code is not there anymore)

---

**Update**

Another common reason why this error appears, is because an exception occurs on the handler method (in our case, `handleChildNotification`). This is easier to identify and troubleshoot with the `pause on exceptions` button of the browser development tools.

Comment: Thanks you!! very detailed answer. That was exactly what was happening

Comment: Today I have faced it again, and the problem was not a ghost method, but and exception happening on the handleEvent method. In this case it was easier to identify with the "pause on exceptions" button

Comment: Hey @GabrielSerranoSalas please feel free to edit my answer and add that info :)

Answer (score 0):

In our case, this error occurred when we were using "cmp or any different value" than what is being passed in the parameter which is "component".

In the second line of code, when we changed "cmp" to "component" - the error got resolved.
handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {

```
    var action = cmp.get("c.shareActionPlanTemplates");
 
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
         //   alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);  
     
 },
```

Comment: fyi, this question was concerning lightning web components - not aura components.

Comment: this is absolute weird, why do we need to call the arguments in such a specific way. it definetely helped in my case as well... so weird. Upvoting

Comment: I also had to fix the way I'm sending the data (it had to be in a 'detail' property)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i forgot to add 'event' in the js method

```
example: 
handleChange(){
   // will throw [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error   
}

handleChange(event){
   
}
```