# 'Sorry to Interrupt' error when trying to save lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have recently added a new column in a lwc, 'reported due date', editable, in a lightning datatable. I also created a validation rule, which is called in the save event, but when i click on save i get the error 'Sorry to interrupt'. With the VR commented, i dont get any error. If i comment the if condition, i dont get that error anymore. Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

The validation rule code is this:

```
        let hasErrors = false;
        let selectedRow = event.detail.selectedRows;
        console.log('tabledata2: ', JSON.stringify(this.data2));
        if (this.data2.length > 0) {
            const firstRow = this.data2[0];
            firstRow.invoiceReportedDueDate = '2023-06-01';
            console.log('First selected row:', JSON.stringify(firstRow));

            // Convert date strings to Date objects
            var invoiceReportedDueDate = new Date(firstRow.invoiceReportedDueDate);
            var dueDate = new Date(firstRow.dueDate);

            // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
            var dif = Math.abs(invoiceReportedDueDate - dueDate);

            // Calculate the difference in days
            var d = dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

            // Log specific properties from the first selected row
            console.log('Color :', JSON.stringify(firstRow.invoiceDunningLevelIcon));
            console.log('DueDate:', JSON.stringify(firstRow.dueDate));
            console.log('ReportedDueDate:', JSON.stringify(firstRow.invoiceReportedDueDate));
            console.log('dif', dif);
            console.log('days', d);
        }

            console.log('draft Value: ', event.detail.draftValues);


            const editedRow = [];

            for(let i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++){
                console.log('Reported Due Date', selectedRow[i].invoiceReportedDueDate );
                console.log('Due Date', selectedRow[i].dueDate);
                console.log('Color1 : ', selectedRow[i].invoiceDunningLevelIcon);
                console.log('reportedDueDate : ', selectedRow[i].invoiceReportedDueDate);
            if((selectedRows[0].invoiceDunningLevelIcon.includes("dunning-level-green") || selectedRows[0].invoiceDunningLevelIcon.includes("dunning-level-blue")) && d > 30 ){
            this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: 'Nu ai voie',
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );

                }
          hasErrors = true;
           }
           return hasErrors;

}
```

and the save event:

```
saveHandleAction(event) {
    // Validation
    let selectedRow = event.detail.selectedRows;

        // Validate the data
       this.validationRule(event);

            // Save the data if there are no validation errors
            try {
                this.inputElement = event.detail.draftValues;
                console.log('Input Event.DraftValues', event.detail.draftValues);
                console.log('Input element', this.inputElement.length);

                this.draftValues = [];
                console.log('This draftValue: ', this.draftValues);

                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Update error:', error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'An Error Occured!!',
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share the full .js code.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/tVPUtscQ

Comment: In the "Sorry to Interrupt" window, what does it say under "Technical Stuff"?

Comment: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs88/auraFW/javascript/f-ORwbkOzgxJoD8-NarJXg/aura_prod.js:999:112
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs88/auraFW/javascript/f-OXg/aura_prod.js:999:305
e.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs88/auraFW/javascript/f-ORwbkOzgxJoD8-NarJXg/aura_prod.js:13:54769
Ha.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs88/auraFW/javascript/f-ORwbkOzgxJoD8-NarJXg/aura_prod.js:13:14725
Ha.handleInlineEditSave()@https://enovos--sat.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:1:94969

Comment: Might this answer your question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343576/noerrorobjectavailable-script-error